# Как в определенном блоке div удалить все запятые?

Tags: javascript, css

```css
.zvuklist {width: 100%;display: table-caption;   padding-bottom: 10px;}
.zvuk {width: 100%;height: 90px; display: flex; justify-content: center;}
.zvuk a {width: 100px;}
.zvuk img {width: 85px;height: 85px;border-radius: 50%;}
.zvuktitle {display: flex;color: black;justify-content: center;}
.zvuktitle a {width: 100px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;font-size: 14px;display: flex;justify-content: space-around;align-items: center;}
.zvukbox {display: flex;align-items: center;}
```

```html
<div class="zvukbox">
            <div class="zvuklist">
                <div class="zvuk">
                     <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%20%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD/" rel="external noopener"><!--dle_image_begin:https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029113-417994353-aleksandr-gavrilin.webp||Александр Гаврилин--><img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029113-417994353-aleksandr-gavrilin.webp" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Александр Гаврилин"><!--dle_image_end--></a> <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%A4%D1%91%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2/" rel="external noopener"><!--dle_image_begin:https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029037-1450940629-fedor-paramonov.webp||Фёдор Парамонов--><img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029037-1450940629-fedor-paramonov.webp" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Фёдор Парамонов"><!--dle_image_end--></a> <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/" rel="external noopener"><!--dle_image_begin:https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029075-1568862793-oleg-novikov.webp||Олег Новиков--><img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029075-1568862793-oleg-novikov.webp" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Олег Новиков"><!--dle_image_end--></a> <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0/" rel="external noopener"><!--dle_image_begin:https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029066-1379947210-alena-falaleeva.webp||Алена Фалалеева--><img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029066-1379947210-alena-falaleeva.webp" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Алена Фалалеева"><!--dle_image_end--></a> <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE/" rel="external noopener"><!--dle_image_begin:https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029061-219115685-mariya-ivaschenko.webp||Мария Иващенко--><img src="https://sefil.ru/uploads/posts/2022-09/1664029061-219115685-mariya-ivaschenko.webp" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Мария Иващенко"><!--dle_image_end--></a> 
                </div>
                <div class="zvuktitle">
                    <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%20%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD/" rel="external noopener"><span class="masha_index masha_index28" rel="28"></span>Александр Гаврилин</a>, <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%A4%D1%91%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2/" rel="external noopener"><span class="masha_index masha_index29" rel="29"></span>Фёдор Парамонов</a>, <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/" rel="external noopener"><span class="masha_index masha_index30" rel="30"></span>Олег Новиков</a>, <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0/" rel="external noopener"><span class="masha_index masha_index31" rel="31"></span>Алена Фалалеева</a>, <a href="https://sefil.ru/tags/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE/" rel="external noopener"><span class="masha_index masha_index32" rel="32"></span>Мария Иващенко</a> <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Есть сайт там с помощью тегов размещается список людей которые озвучили фильм, вопрос как можно удалить запятые не делая этого в ручную. Может есть метод через css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему они стоят на таком подозрительном расстоянии от текста? Лучше код приложите

Comment: Просто это теги, причем фото отдельным доп полем, а имена отдельным и чтобы вывести их друг под другом использовал display: table-caption;

Comment: *"не делая этого в ручную"* --- а чём сложность? Открыть любой редактор текста и сделать замену всех `</a>,` на `</a>`. Это дело 3 секунд

Comment: Сложность в том, что на страницу информация выводится из базы, и ваш вариант не подходит.

Comment: В базе лежит html?

Comment: В таком случае надо в базе и поправить: сделать запрос..... либо просто открыть dump, сделать то, что я написал, и вернуть обратно.

Comment: Там тысячи фильмов, может тогда подскажите как запрос сделать. И нет я просто выложил уже готовый html который выводится после обработки. Если в html то выводится так  <div class="zvukbox">
            <div class="zvuklist">
                <div class="zvuk">
                     [xfgiven_scoring][xfvalue_scoring] [/xfgiven_scoring]
                </div>
                <div class="zvuktitle">
                 [xfgiven_scoring2][xfvalue_scoring2] <br><br>[/xfgiven_scoring2]
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

Comment: ну если в базе хранятся данные, а не html, то значит надо в коде просто одну запятую урбать ...не ясно в чём такие сложности